# cakePhp adding record problem

Tags: cakephp, addition, relationship

I have 3 tables:
`item      {name,id,category_id}

category   {id,name,section_id}

sections   {id,name}`

As you can see, each item is related to a category, and each category is related to a section. 
I used the bake option and got it all baked, well, not all..
since the Category.name can be duplicated, and since it is the displayed field, I find my self in a situation which prevent me of knowing which category I really use.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer was:
Using `find('list')`, with `recursive` option ON, and with 3 fields instead of two.
That way it grouped the categories under the sections.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. Add to your Category model:

```
    var $virtualFields = array(
       'category_unique_name' => 'CONCAT(Category.name, "-", Category.id)'
    );

    var $displayField = 'category_unique_name';
```

This virtual field you can use to tell which category is which based on the combination of its id and name. There are some limitations to virtual fields, however. Read about it here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1608/Virtual-fields#!/view/1608/Virtual-fields

Comment: after accepting your answer I understood that it wasn't what i need, the problem is that the virtualField are limited to the same model and cannot access data from other model, while in query